# Build command failed

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I use android studio preview beta 4 and I get Telegram source code from https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram when I open project it build and get this error :

> Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/app source code/Telegram-FOSS-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>   C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk
>   Error:(183, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File
>   Error:(183, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   Open File

I use latest NDK  android-ndk-r16-beta1-windows-x86 .
error is in line 100 of add-application.mk and it is:

```
ifndef _build_script
    $(call __ndk_info,Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: 
$(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
    $(call __ndk_error,Aborting...)
endif
```

so the add-application.mk I used is in this URL :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/froyo/build/core/add-application.mk

Answer (score 1):

Your put project in `C:\Users\M\Desktop\app source code\Telegram-FOSS-master\TMessagesProj` which has spaces. This won't work with NDK. Move your project to path without spaces.

Comment: thanks for replay ,I changed the name and delete space  but the error stay same .

Comment: ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=apps/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=apps\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...)

Comment: it is to long error but the comment limited with 600 characters .

Comment: You can edit your question; also you can copy the log to pastebin and put here a link. The fragment you posted does not contain enough info.

Comment: Maybe you did not clean up the `build` and `.externalNativeBuild` directories?